# Better to have two variables to designate whether a variable exists, or one

Tags: design

Lets say I have a string variable `FirstName`. `FirstName` can be null. I need to know if `FirstName` exists or not.

Is it better to just use one variable: `FirstName` and if `FirstName` is empty assume that it doesn't exists

OR

Create two variables:
`Boolean HasFirstName` and `String FirstName`

The benefits of this is I know positively that `FirstName` doesn't exist but on the down side it creates two variables.

Comment: Some languages make a distinction between `firstName == null` and `firstName == ""`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would argue against both choices and would use an [option type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type) instead. An option type either contains no value or, or in this case, a string.

Many languages, especially functional ones, have such types built-in. Even if your chosen language doesn't support it directly, an `Option<T>` is a simple type to create.